# Prevent External Requests (scripts, etc) on Localhost?

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost

Is there any way to prevent a site from requesting or loading any third party resources?  Specifically, when I'm working on my localhost, I want to block all external request for the times that my bandwidth is lacking (at a coffee shop or other).

I know I can go through with php and/or javascript and conditionally load scripts, such as:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost'){
}
```

But I want to see if I can globally block plugins and anything else from trying to access the internet.

Is there any way via .htaccess, php in the header, or even through WAMP settings?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I feel the best way to do this is to add a concept of environments to your development framework. For example in your .htaccess you could do:

`SetEnv ENV dev`

Then in your config/boostrap you can do a:

```
$env = getenv('ENV');
define('APP_ENV', $env ? $env : 'prod');
```

Now you can easily use `APP_ENV` to conditionally do/output things like a Facebook iFrame or an api request. You could also jsut define this directly in a configuration file or script instead of passing it through an htaccess. Doesnt really matter.